# Different subsection format if no title is given

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I want to have subsections appear like "Article 1: Foo" when I enter `\subsection{Foo}`, but like "Article 1" (without the colon) when I enter `\subsection{}` (without a title). Is there a way to do this?

Here's a MWE of what I have now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcounter{artikel}
\setcounter{artikel}{1}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{artikel}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{Article \thesubsection: \refstepcounter{artikel}}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Foo}
\subsection{}

\end{document}
```

Which produces

**Article 1: Foo**

**Article 2:**

But I want it to produce:

**Article 1: Foo**

**Article 2**

Comment: Should be possible, but the implementation depends on the document class

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am using the `article` class. I added a MWE for clarity.

Comment: The usual subsection numbers (in front of the subsection title) should vanish and be replaced by Article ....?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's right, with the number after Article being the subsection number (or rather another predefined counter, as I want the subsection nubers to increase throughout several sections). I just realized this last point might be important for the answer, will edit the MWE.

Comment: Perhaps `titlesec` is the easier option here

Comment: why a new counter? you can redefine subsection's counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with`etoolbox` and the `explicit`option of `titlesec`. Also note that if you want to use `starred` subsections, you can have a different formatting with the `numberless` key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{artikel}
\setcounter{artikel}{1}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{artikel}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{Article \thesubsection\notblank{#1}{:~}{}#1\refstepcounter{artikel}}

\begin{document}

    \subsection{Foo}
    \subsection{ }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This nearly works, but now the subsection title ('Foo' in the example) drops out. It can be replaced by changing the last argument of `\titleformat` to `Article \thesubsection\notblank{#1}{:}{} #1\refstepcounter{artikel}`

Comment: Oops! You're right, I had forgotten to add `#1`, as required by the explicit option. It's corrected now. Thanks for pointing it.